# how do I select all records that have an event datetime within 1 hour before

Tags: mysql, php, datetime

how do I select all records that have an event datetime within 1 hour before, for example mysql select all that time_diff less than 1 hour from datetime? its for a reminder email i want to make on a cronjob can you help with this sql query?

```
$todays_date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$today=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$e="";
require("../../php_includes/db_conx.php");
require("db_conx.php");
$todays_year=date('Y'); // Y-m-d H:i:s
$todays_month=date('m'); // Y-m-d H:i:s
$todays_day=date('d'); // Y-m-d H:i:s
$todays_hour=date('H'); // Y-m-d H:i:s
$Mtoday_hour=$todays_hour+1; // Y-m-d H:i:s
$sql="SELECT * FROM events WHERE evt_start BETWEEN '$todays_year-$todays_month-$todays_day $Mtoday_hour:00:00' AND '$todays_year-$todays_month-$todays_day $Mtoday_hour:59:59' AND email_sent_status='0' LIMIT 10";
//2022-08-25 14:00:00
echo "BETWEEN $todays_year-$todays_month-$todays_day $Mtoday_hour:00:00 AND $todays_year-$todays_month-$todays_day $Mtoday_hour:59:59 ";

$query=mysqli_query($db_conx_crn, $sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, store dates in `DATE`, `DATETIME`, *or* `TIMESTAMP`; do not store year, month, etc, separately.

Then

```
SELECT * FROM events 
    WHERE evt_start >= CURDATE()
      AND evt_start  < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
      AND status = 0
    ORDER BY ...  -- otherwise which 10 do you want??
    LIMIT 10;
```

`CURDATE()` is midnight this morning.  Interval can take other intervals (eg `DAY`), but the keyword is always singular (unlike English).  Eg ,`INTERVAL 7 DAY` represents one week.

And have, for a bit of extra performance, have

```
INDEX(status, evt_start)
```

Comment: the evt_start and end are both datetime evt_id bigint(20) Auto Increment 
evt_start datetime 
evt_end datetime 
evt_text text 
evt_color varchar(7) 
username varchar(15) 
email_sent_status varchar(1) [0]

Comment: i tried SELECT * FROM events WHERE evt_start <= CURDATE() AND email_sent_status = 0 
OR evt_start <= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR AND email_sent_status = 0 LIMIT 10 
and it dosnt show a test event i seup with less than 1 hour till evt start time, any ideas why?

Comment: @uk_user2014 - Bad boolean.  What is before (<=) an hour from now is also before now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the 1 reply and some more research i fixed using the following

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE evt_start <= CURDATE() AND email_sent_status = 0 
OR evt_start <= NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR AND email_sent_status = 0 LIMIT 10
```